# Bootstrap - list of text of icons - achieving consistent horizontal alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

The problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/3jAk2/

```
<div><i class='icon-camera-retro'></i> Text text text</div>
<div><i class='icon-download'></i> Text text text</div>
```

As you could see - icons and text are shifted relatively to vertical 'columns' for each of them. 

That's my solution:
http://jsbin.com/iguH/6/edit

Maybe there is better/more elegant or proper/built in in bootstrap ones?

ps
Another problem that I didnt yet solved - what if text is multilined? And it still need to be in its column - not wraps icon?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a slightly different approach. I would use background images with padding. This would also fix your multiline issue.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/3jAk2/1/

```
div {
    padding-left:20px;
    background:url('yourURL') no-repeat left 2px;
    background-size: 15px 15px;
}
```

Comment: How to do that with glyphs? :) It is a big deal - FontAwesome contains only unicode characters and it rocks too hard to replace it. Pure unicode without png's also rocks.

Comment: To do it with glyphs would involve span tags, floating, and bg positioning.

Comment: How do you put glyph to page with `background`?

Comment: That's a good solution too. Making use of `Padding-left` will always ensure no wrapping takes place and all lefthand edges are aligned